# Parse html tags in Angular +2 coming from php

Tags: angular

I have this in php

```
foreach ($post_hashtags as $post_hashtag) {
  $post_txt = str_replace('#[' . $post_hashtag['hash'] . ']', "<a style='cursor:pointer;' (click)='getByTag(" . $post_hashtag['id'] . ")'>#" . $post_hashtag['tag'] . "</a>", $post_txt);
  }
```

I try to read it in my html with two ways

(1)

```
<p [innerHTML]="data.text"></p>          //frist way

<p>{{data.text}}</p>                    //second way
```

Output:

```
test

<a style='cursor:pointer;'  (click)='getByTag(8269)'>#test</a>
```

How can I parse it to make my (click) understood by Angular?

Comment: can you please share your actual raw output coming from `data.text` property ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular is doing [Sanitization](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts) it means that interpolated content is always escaped—the HTML isn't interpreted and the browser displays angle brackets in the element's text content.

This is for security purpose. In deed in your code if attacker can change any value in  $post_hashtag he could inject script in your page.

If you still want to do that (I strongly advice against it) you can use the  [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) like:

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.myValue = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(myHtmlValue);
}
```

For more information take a look at https://angular.io/guide/security#security

Comment: In only sets the innerHtml. But you also need to bind the `getByTag(8269)` method with **click** event.

Comment: yes i didn't see that part... It's bad design it should return json and create the link from it.

Comment: Yes i also agree with you. Its totally a bad practice. May be the api was designed considering juery/ajax application pattern.